# Inherit ArrayList from superclass

Tags: java, arraylist, superclass

I have an ArrayList in a class called QuantityCatalogue and i made another class that extends the first class.(public class Buy extends QuantityCatalogue).How can i inherit the ArrayList that i made in QuantityCatalogue and use it in Buy class?
Is this right?

```
public class Buy extends QuantityCatalogue
{
    public Buy(ArrayList<String> items,ArrayList<Integer> quantity)
    {
        super(items,quantity);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "use"?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your problem, but you might want to set the visibility modifier of the array list to "protected" to make it visible for inheriting classes.

Comment: Did you try it? Does it work?

Comment: sorry could you provide an example of "usage" of ArrayList you are looking for and at least explain what it should look like? Thus far I don't see it in the provided code.

Comment: I hava made an ArrayList in a class and i want to modify it in another class.How can i do this?
For example the ArrayList i made has the quantity of some products and i made another class Buy where if someone buys a product the ArrayList quantity of this product will be -1.

Comment: generally that ArrayList field is private, your superclass has public void setMyPrettyList (ArrayList list) method, and you use this.setMyPrettyList(someList) in your subclass to set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a private ArrayList field in superclass, declare a public setter method in supeclass, and in your subclass call this setter method to set the field'value:

```
 public class QuantityCatalogue {
        private ArrayList<String> items;

            //this method helps us change the value of field items
        public void setItems(ArrayList<String> items) {
            this.items = items;
        }

          .....
    }

    public class Buy extends QuantityCatalogue {
        public void someMethod(ArrayList<String> items) {
            //call setItems method of superclass
            this.setItems(items);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare it `protected` in the super class, then the variable is also visible to child classes. `public` is also possible but possibly opens the *variable scope* too much for your use case. And if your child class is in the same package, you can also use the default modifier.

A completely different option is to provide a getter/setter functions like this:

```
private ArrayList<String> items;

protected ArrayList<String> getItems() {
    return items;
}

protected void setItems(ArrayList<String> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
```

Comment: @JBNizet depends on what you need it for. I just wanted to show _all_ options

Comment: @DanielAlder Then you should put a warning about `public`, because it does not look like a good choice in this particular case.

Comment: It is better to declare field private and provide setter to change its value.